# Primes of the form $f(n)+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, products

Maybe , someone has already checked this. In this case, I will soon delete the question.

Define $$f(n):=\prod_{j=1}^n F_j$$ where $F_j$ denotes the $j$-th Fibonacci-number.

- $f(n)-1$ is prime for $n=4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15$ and no other positive integer $n\le 400$
- $f(n)+1$ is prime for $n=1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 22, 28$ and no other positive integer $n\le 400$

> Are other primes of the form $f(n)\pm 1$ known  ? If yes, which is the next larger one for each type ?

Chances for a prime are not bad : For $n\ge 284$ , there is no prime factor $p\le 293$.

Comment: Hint: oeis ... ;)

Comment: Damn , I guessed it.

Comment: Search limit extended to $n=500$ , no further PRP's

Comment: For the numbers of the form $f(n)+1$ no additional $n<1500$ results in a prime.

Comment: @jorisperrenet What is you search limit for the case $f(n)-1$ ?

Comment: @Peter, I have not searched it yet and will probably not search it for the rest of this week.

Comment: @Peter, I just searched the numbers of the form $f(n)-1$ and found no possible primes for $n \leq 1700$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a full answer, just a thought on the prime randomness:

The fibonacci numbers are about

$$F_n\sim \frac{\phi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}$$

where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Then $f(n)$ grows as

$$f(n)=\prod_{i=1}^n F_i\sim \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\phi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{\frac{\phi^{n(n+1)}}{5^{n}}}$$

Then the probability that there is a prime $1$ above or below this number is about

$$P=2\cdot \frac{2}{\log\left(\frac{\phi^{n(n+1)}}{5^{n}}\right)}=\frac{4}{n(n+1)\log(\phi)-n\log(5)}$$

which is $O(n^{-2})$. Since

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$$

we would expect that the number of such primes to be finite.

Comment: Note that for $n > 1500$ your probability $P$ increases by at least a factor $14.5$ due to the fact that $f(n)$ cannot be divisible by any factor of one of the first $1500$ fibonacci numbers. Since this factor does not increase rapidly I think that most of the heuristics will still hold.